Error: Configuration must contain `projectId` when trying to deploy Sanity Studio
I'm building a portfolio website using Nextjs15 and Sanity CMS v3. I'm using typscript with nextjs but i initialized sanity using js. While trying to deploy sanity studio, i get the error Error: Configuration must contain projectId. Also, I embedded sanity studio within my nextjs project and when I go to http:localhost:3000/studio, I'm greeted with Tool not found: studio, however I can access structure, vision etc, but only temporarily until I get a 404 error. I tried checking cors in the sanity project itself but that's already configured properly. I tried removing .env.local (which my projectId is) from gitignore. I can also see the projectId logged when I try to deploy the studio.
Here's my sanity.config.js:
"use client";

import { visionTool } from "@sanity/vision";
import { defineConfig } from "sanity";
import { structureTool } from "sanity/structure";

// Go to https://www.sanity.io/docs/api-versioning to learn how API versioning works
import { apiVersion, dataset, projectId } from "./sanity/env";
import { schema } from "./sanity/schemaTypes";
import { structure } from "./sanity/structure";

console.log("projectId", projectId);

export default defineConfig({
    basePath: "/",
    projectId,
    dataset,
    // Add and edit the content schema in the './sanity/schemaTypes' folder
    schema,
    plugins: [
        structureTool({ structure }),
        // Vision is for querying with GROQ from inside the Studio
        // https://www.sanity.io/docs/the-vision-plugin
        visionTool({ defaultApiVersion: apiVersion }),
    ],
});

my sanity.cli.js:
import { defineCliConfig } from "sanity/cli";

const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID;
const dataset = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET;
const studioHost = "xxxxxx";

export default defineCliConfig({
    api: { projectId, dataset },
    studioHost: studioHost,
});

my env.js:
export const apiVersion = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_VERSION || "2024-11-30";
export const dataset = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET;
export const projectId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID;

my .env.example & .env.local:
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID=xxxxxxx
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET=production
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/

I also tried deleting .env.example and using .env instead of .env.local:
my .env:
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID = "xxxxxxxx"
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET = "production"
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000/"

Note that when I use .env I get this error instead: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
